# C - Recursion array checking

Tags: c, recursion

i would like to ask about the array recursion in C, Let say i have an array in float

```
 float arr[] = {12.5, 5.5, 6.0, 18.0};
```

i want to count the number which is greater than 10, so the result should be 2. However, below is what i did

```
int cntArray(float arr[], int size) 
{
    int number = 0;
    if((cntArray(&arr[1], size - 1))>=5)
        number++;

    return number;
}

int main() 
{
    float arr[] = {12.5, 5.5, 6.0, 18.0};
    int result;

    result = cntArray(arr, 4);

    printf("The result is : %d", result);
}
```

But it returns 0 as result, any solutions for it? Thanks

Comment: Please align your code properly

Comment: `int cntArray(float arr[], int size){
 int number = 0;
 if((cntArray(&arr[1], size - 1))>=5)
   number++;

 return number;}` Debug this function by manually executing each line using pen and paper. You will find your mistake.

Comment: You should read about recursion in detail. You have written the recursive calling step. But you have missed the final step where recursion unrolls itself.

Comment: `return size ? ((*arr>=10) + cntArray(arr + 1, size - 1)) : 0;` That's it.

Comment: @WhozCraig : Thats a Pretty one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int cntArray(float arr[], int size) {
    int number = 0;
    if (size > 0) number = cntArray(&arr[1], size - 1);
    if (arr[0] > 10) number += 1;
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `cntArray()` function lacks a recursion base case, and also seems to hardcode the wrong value (`5` instead of `10`).

It should be something like:

```
int cntArray(const float *arr, size_t size)
{
  if(size > 0)
  {
    /* Count the first element, then recurse. */
    const int count = arr[0] >= 10.f;
    return count + cntArray(arr + 1, size -1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll totally +1 this if you change `const int *arr` to `const float *arr` =P

Answer (score 3):

Another example:

```
int cntArray(float arr[], int size) {
        if (!size) return 0;

        return (arr[0] > 10.0 ? 1 : 0) + cntArray(&arr[1], size - 1);
}
```

Edit #1 (in reply to comment):

This simply evaluate through a ternary operator (?:) if the first index of arr[] is greater than 10.0. If true, 1 will be the lvalue, otherwise will be 0. The lvalue of cntArray(&arr[1], size - 1) (which will process the next element on the array after decrementing size and if size is different than 0, which in this case will immediately return 0) will be added to the lvalue of the ternary operator. Applying this recurring logic, the aftermath will be the number of elements in the array that are greater than 10.0.

Comment: You should add some text explaining what this does and how it works

Answer (score 2):

```
int cntArray(float arr[], int size){
    int number = 0;
    if((number = cntArray(&arr[1], size - 1))>=5)
        number++;
    return number;
}
```

You maybe want to change `5` to `10`.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is severely flawed: You don't actually check if a *value in the array* is larger than `10`. you also always return `number` which will always be zero meaning the condition will always be false.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what does this portion of your code does.

```
if((cntArray(&arr[1], size - 1))>=5)
   number++;
```

I would something like this instead:

```
int cntArray(float arr[], int index, int size){
    if (index == size) return 0;  // base case

    int rest = cntArray(arr, index + 1, size);  // how many elements are greater
                                                // then 10 in rest of the array
    if (arr[index] > 10)
        return rest + 1;
    else
        return rest;
}
```

And call it in the main like this:

```
cntArray(arr, 0, 4);
```